# TYPO3 backend list view 'required' field validation, highlight like tx-news

Tags: validation, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news, required-field

I'm working on a custom extension where a title is absolutely required, the data is only edited in the backend trough the list module.

I did ad `'eval' => 'required'` to the title column in the TCA but that gives only an error message if the title is null on saving. (documentation : [TCAReference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Input/Index.html#))

I'd like to have the field highlighted as happens in tx-news (red exclamation marks get added to field name and tab and the field gets a red outline)

**EDIT: this is default behaviour** for some reason my localhost fumbled for a period ...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know this is the default behaivor for TYPO3 7.6. Your own TCA is validated on the same way. When you leave the focus on an field and its failed validation it is marked like your screenshot. You can see the same behaivor on pages or other content elements.

Comment: you are right, on my localhost xampp installation I sometimes have strange surprises.. I tested it in a simple extension and it went exactly like that, this time not even a cache problem ...